# QGIS - split polyline

Tags: qgis, editing, splitting

I need to create a shapefile with crossed streets. I can't split the lines to number each segment with the house number ranges.

Comment: You have two different questions here. For splitting lines in QGIS, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48461/ Another term for this is planarize. For the tracing part, what are you tracing from? A scanned image? Another vector layer?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange Cristian! Please note that the format of this site limits each thread to exactly one question. I've therefore removed the second question. Please open a separate thread for it.

Comment: Thanks Chris W! I´ll check the link. Then, i´ll draw the lines over the street´s map handly.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody thanks a lot. Finally, I did it. Was to easy (when you know how). In QGIS 2.8.1 the tool is SPLIT LINES WITH LINES (on the V. Overlay, on Geoalgorithms, from Advanced Interface). I came there thanks to Chris W advice.

Comment: Well Maybe next time express your issue with a picture! I'm still not sure what the problem is like =/ because it's easy to solve.